# Выделить повторяющийся блок try-catch в отдельный метод

Tags: c#, asp.net, nancy, serilog

Делаю серверную часть на NancyFramework. Выделил базовый модуль, от которого наследуются все остальные.

BaseModule. В нём я описал методы логирования и конвертации json в понятные мне классы, т.к. этот код постоянно повторяется:

```
public abstract class BaseModule : NancyModule
{
    public BaseModule() : base("/") { }

    protected Response CreateExceptionResponse(string json, string typeException, HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) =>
        new()
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Contents = stream =>
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
                writer.Write(json);
            },
            ReasonPhrase = typeException,
            StatusCode = statusCode
        };

    protected Response BadRequest(string exceptionMessage) =>
        new()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            Contents = stream =>
            {
                var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
                writer.Write(exceptionMessage);
            },
        };

    protected string CreateLogByContext(NancyContext context)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new()
        {
            { nameof(Context.Request.Body), context.Request.Body.AsString() }
        };
        return $"The server received a request. Request body:\n" +
            $"{JsonSerializer.Serialize(dic, CreateSerializerOptions()).Replace(@"\", string.Empty)}";
    }

    protected string CreateReturnLog(string json) =>
        $"The server successfully processed the request. Server response to client:\n{json}";

    protected JsonSerializerOptions CreateSerializerOptions()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
            Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
            AllowTrailingCommas = true,
            NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
        return options;
    }
}
```

Далее создал OrderModule, который как раз-таки занимается обработкой запросов:

```
public class OrderModule : BaseModule
{
    private readonly IConfigCache _configCache;
    private readonly OrderController _orderController;

    public OrderModule(IOrderCache orderCache, IConfigCache configCache) : base()
    {
        _configCache = configCache;
        _orderController = new(orderCache);

        Get("/orders/{orderId}", parameters =>
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information(CreateLogByContext(Context));
                var order = _orderController.GetOrderById(parameters.orderId);

                var returnJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<OrderDto>(order);
                Log.Information(CreateReturnLog(returnJson));
                return returnJson;
            }
            catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ex.CreateDictionary(), CreateSerializerOptions());
                Log.Error(ex, json);
                return CreateExceptionResponse(json, nameof(EntityNotFoundException));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        });

        Get("/orders", parameters =>
        {
            Log.Information(CreateLogByContext(Context));
            var orders = _orderController.GetOrders();

            var returnJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(orders);
            Log.Information(CreateReturnLog(returnJson));
            return returnJson;
        });

        Get("/order/create/{waiterId}/{tableId}", parameters =>
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information(CreateLogByContext(Context));
                var waiterId = parameters.waiterId;
                var tableId = parameters.tableId;
                var order = _orderController.CreateOrder(waiterId, tableId);

                var returnJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<OrderDto>(order);
                Log.Information(CreateReturnLog(returnJson));
                return returnJson;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        });

        Post("/order/submitChanges", parameters =>
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Information(CreateLogByContext(Context));
                var json = Request.Body.AsString();
                var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionDto>(json);
                var order = _orderController.SubmitChanges(obj);

                var returnJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(order);
                Log.Information(CreateReturnLog(returnJson));
                return returnJson;
            }
            catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ex.CreateDictionary(), CreateSerializerOptions());
                Log.Error(ex, json);
                return CreateExceptionResponse(json, nameof(EntityNotFoundException));
            }
            catch (InvalidSessionException ex)
            {
                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ex.CreateDictionary(), CreateSerializerOptions());
                Log.Error(ex, json);
                return CreateExceptionResponse(json, nameof(InvalidSessionException));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, ex.Message);
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Вставил не весь код, т.к. он гораздо длиннее.

Собственно, сама проблема - мне крайне сильно не нравится то, что в начале каждого запроса я пишу код для логирования тела запроса, логирование перед тем, как отправить ответ и try-catch. В OrderModule это ярко видно, что код повторяется постоянно. Можно ли как-нибудь это вынести в отдельный метод, в который вынести всю эту обработку исключений и тд? Чтоб я просто передавал в него нужный метод, который должен отработать и получал ответ. Может как-нибудь реализовать это через дженерики и `Func<out T>`?

Логирую с помощью Serilog.

Comment: Кстати, хороший вопрос. Интересно будет посмотреть ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если важен стектрейс, то можно использовать [ExceptionDispatchInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo).

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
    LogException(edi);
}
```

```
private void LogException(ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
{
    try
    {
        edi.Throw();
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (InvalidSessionException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Окей если надо завернуть метод в делегат (хотя вы и так в делегате), то как-то так

```
private T WithException<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (InvalidSessionException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
return WithException(() => 42 / 0);
```

Асинхронно вот так

```
private async Task<T> WithException<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (InvalidSessionException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Обработка исключений мне важна в первую очередь, чтоб передать само исключение на клиент, чтобы разработчик смог как-либо его обработать. Так же, само исключение обязательно на сервере нужно залогировать. Я логирую уже сериализованное исключение. Обратите внимание, я сериализую исключения в json и передаю их со статусом InternalServerError. Клиент получает ответ и десериализует его обратно в исключение и выкидывает его через `throw`. Многие исключения у меня кастомные, поэтому просто запихнуть всё в `*Exception*.Message` не получится. Могу дополнить ответ и привести их код.

Comment: @Frehzy вы не поняли ответ. Никто не запрещает вам менять сигнатуру метода `LogException` как захочется. Формируйте в нем ответы, сериализуйте, что хотите делайте. Смысл EDI в том, что вы можете схватить оригинальное исключение, унести куда угодно и выбросить там, получив стектрейс именно из того места, где оно было захвачено, а не где повторно выброшено.

Comment: Ааа, всё, понял-понял. Почитал ещё немного инфы про этот класс. Да, это решение подходит. Это здорово сократит количество кода. Спасибо. Прикрутить ещё сверху этого логирование тела запроса и тела ответа (то, что находится в блоке `try`) и идеально будет

Comment: Не, это то понятно, что Func<T> и Task<Func<T>>. Почему я это упомянул - дело в том, что методы у меня совершенно разные: `public OrderDto GetOrderById(dynamic id)` `public List<OrderDto> GetOrders()` `public OrderDto CreateOrder(dynamic waiterId, dynamic tableId)` `public OrderDto SubmitChanges(SessionDto session)` (пример методов). Количество параметров везде разное. Ладно, если-бы они имели одинаковое количество параметров. Извините, что не упомянул. Вот я и думаю, как-бы сделать правильнее этот Func

Comment: @Frehzy а кто вам сказал, что аргументы надо в функцию запихивать? В примере выше никаких аргументов нет `(() => здесь любой код, который возвращает T)` то есть аргументы не надо никуда тащить.

Comment: А, точно. Всё, понял. Спасибо, ещё раз